# Average date in many date intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many date intervals in a table:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-10 |
| 2019-01-11 | 2019-04-20 |
| 2020-11-11 | 2020-12-12 |

I need the most common date between all of them. I know maybe it is more than one. If I have all dates and ocurrences it's also fine.

The table has ~100000 records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expected results and what have you tried?

Comment: So have you tried? Why didn't it work? A quick search would have told you that getting both an average (`AVG`) and the difference between two dates (`DATEDIFF`) is very easy, so what was the problem when you tried to combine those 2 functions?

Comment: Try counting the rows with the same date intervals. The count(*) with the highest number is the most common date interval. If you want to count a date which might be in both and you dont care about the interval use UNION ALL between start and end date and then count the rows.

Comment: Also show your expected results for the provided sample data.

Comment: Do you want the most common date interval, or the most common date within all intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force method is to break the time periods into individual days.  Then aggregate and pull the days with the maximum counts.

You can do this using a recursive CTE:

```
with d as (
      select s, e
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, s), e
      from d
      where s < e
     )
select top (1) with ties s, count(*) as overlaps
from d
group by s
order by dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc);
```

If your intervals could have 100 or more days, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e0f0f5835d3a7ee558cdb1cfc74edf8) is a db<>fiddle.